# Laravel DB::RAW() NOT IN not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Hello I have 5 records on `cards` table,
and when I use not in on `phpmyadmin` it's working

`SELECT id FROM cards WHERE id NOT IN (1,2)`

[image]

but when I used not in on Laravel it's not working, and it only bind on 1st

```
$test = "1,2";

$cards = DB::SELECT(DB::RAW("SELECT id FROM cards WHERE id NOT IN (:exception)"), ['exception'=>$test]);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($cards);
echo "</pre>";
```

[image]

I'm using this guide to avoid SQL Injection:
http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

Answer (score 3):

```
DB::table('cards')->whereRaw('id NOT IN(".$test.")')->get();
```

Please try this code instead.

Comment: I need to use DB::RAW() cause I have a long query, this is just a sample to make question easier to understand.

Comment: $cards = DB::SELECT(DB::RAW("SELECT id FROM cards WHERE id NOT IN (".$test.")"));
this one ?

Comment: I need to use http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: ok actually the problem is with commas , system is assuming single character $test = "1"; instead of $test = "1,2";

Comment: i think no problem if you have long query then also you have to use DB::table with in between Raw() where it is needed i dnt think so this method fails

Comment: alternatively you can put comment in fidelopers 's above post to get solution :P :)